# Call method with special characters in name from C#

Tags: c#, clr, ikvm

When using ikvmc to compile JAR to DLL, it generates methods and classes with funny names, like

```
TestClass.__<clinit>(object X);
```

or

```
TestClass$1.MethodName();
```

I wish to call and/or override them from the C# client. How can I achieve this without using Reflection?

Update: Not only call, but override in inherited classes too...

Comment: Since these are not valid C# identifies, your only option it to use reflection in some form.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to override/call the static initializer and anonymous inner classes? Sound like a very large hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use reflection at least for creation of delegate:

```
var assembly = typeof(SomeJarToDllAssembly.SomeType).Assembly;
var type_TestClass1 = assembly.GetType("TestClass$1");
var method_clinit = type_TestClass.GetMethod("__<clinit>");
var dlgClinit = (Action<object>)Delegate.Create(type_TestClass, method_clinit);

// call delegate like normal method (it's fast as normal method calling)
dlgClinit(new object());
```

There are several cases how correctly create delegates. See the MSDN reference guide: [System.Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) and the `CreateDelegate` methods.

Comment: I've forgot about CreateDelegate, thanks. Now I'd better make some extension method and a clever regex... there are *lots* of places where this would be useful.

Comment: Also, another horrible question: how to _override_ these methods? :)

Comment: I think, you must generate valid IL and then compile it. You can create *.il files and use ilasm.exe or you can use Reflection.Emit do create the assemblies programatically. The IL is not so hard. If you create sample override method in C# and then disamble it, you will see what to do. Unfortunatelly, it's will taky time to polish the IL generator.